# typo3 flexform for plugin with folders

Tags: typo3, flexform

I have created a plugin for an extension + some Flexform for this plugin (not TCA).
This works so far.

Now I would like to extend the backend view of this plugin and use several folders for the flexform.
Unfortunately I don't get this working. What I tried so far is to have two structures inside `<sheets>`
This is a structure just to get it working with the two folders. The fields will be specified in more detail once the setup with the folders will work!

```
<T3DataStructure>
  <meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
  </meta>
  <sheets>
    <Folder1>
    <sDEF>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>Folder1</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.flexform.field11>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field11</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field11>
          <settings.flexform.field12>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field12</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field12>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
    </Folder1>
    <Folder2>
    <sDEF>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>Folder2</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.flexform.field21>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field21</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field21>
          <settings.flexform.field22>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field22</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field22>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
    </Folder1>
  </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Update:
based on answer of Julian Hofmann my structure now looks like:

```
<T3DataStructure>
  <meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
  </meta>
  <sheets>
    <sDEF>
    <Folder1>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>Folder1</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.flexform.field11>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field11</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field11>
          <settings.flexform.field12>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field12</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field12>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </Folder1>
    <Folder2>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>Folder2</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.flexform.field21>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field21</label>
              <onChange>reload</onChange>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field21>
          <settings.flexform.field22>
            <TCEforms>
              <exclude>1</exclude>
              <label>Field22</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>30</size>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.flexform.field22>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </Folder2>
    </sDEF>
  </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

I now get:

```
PHP Warning: Undefined array key "ROOT" in /var/www/html/averlon.de/av_t3test/public/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Container/FlexFormNoTabsContainer.php line 62
```

Comment: What does not work and what do you expect? Do you want to select multiple pages (or sysfolders) or directories of the filesystem? Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: no, the intention is to have - I don't know what the correct expression is - multiple TABS in the Plugin Options pane.
I guess, I have to work with "TYPES" and "PALETTES", probably.
Similar like a tt_content view has "General", "Plugin", "Appearance" ....

Comment: `<sDEF>` is the sheets node. For multiple sheets, this subtree has to be copied/modified. Fo for your folders you'll need `<T3DataStructure><sheets><Folder1><ROOT>...</ROOT></Folder1><Folder2><ROOT>...</ROOT></Folder2></sheets></T3DataStructure>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Working Example based from Extension News:

https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/main/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_tag_list.xml

```xml
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <!--
            ################################
              Tab 1
            ################################
        -->
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>TAB 1</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <!-- order -->
                    <settings.orderBy>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>orderBy</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                                <items>
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1">
                                        <numIndex index="0">tstamp</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">tstamp</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="3">
                                        <numIndex index="0">crdate</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">crdate</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="4">
                                        <numIndex index="0">title</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">title</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.orderBy>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
        <!--
            ################################
              Tab 2
            ################################
        -->
        <additional>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Tab 2</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.media.maxWidth>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>mediaMaxWidth</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>input</type>
                                <size>5</size>
                                <eval>num</eval>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.media.maxWidth>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </additional>

        <!--
            ################################
              Tab 3
            ################################
        -->
        <template>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Tab 3</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <!-- Template Layout -->
                    <settings.templateLayout>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>templateLayout</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
                                <items>
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.templateLayout>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </template>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Comment: thanks for this example. I adopted this structure to my definitions and this now works.
Now my next challenge is to have some fields on x-columns (horizontal) instead having them all under each other in a vertical line.
But I think I have to ask this in a separate question.

Comment: Flexforms have (more or less) the same syntax as TCA definitions. At least in the docu for Flexforms there is a reference to the TCA Reference manual.
Is there a way to convert the TCA files to XML. TCA files with "'xxxx' => [" are not XML. I don't know what syntax this is (Object definition???)?

Comment: Hi @avalon, the TCA is a PHP-Array. You can adopt this as example as XML-Array:

```php
'key' => [
 'label' => 'My label',
 'config' => [
  'type' => 'input',
  'size' => 5,
  'eval' => 'trim'
 ]
]

```


```xml
<key>
 <label>My label</label>
 <config>
  <type>input</type>
  <size>5</size>
  <eval>trim</eval>
 </config>
</key>
```

Comment: found the solution: The structure is meanwhile deprecated and replaced by the filed type "File" which is easier to configure in XML and I found an example as well.
Thanks for help!